# Combine Instagram JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, json, object, instagram

I am having a complete brain fail today and cannot figure out how to combine two JSON objects from the Instagram API.

They look a little something like this:

```
{
  "pagination": {
    ...
  },
  "meta": {
    ...
  },
  "data": [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    },
  ]
}
```

The way that the Instagram API works is it will only send you a maximum of 20 data items at a time, it then sends a `"next_url"` parameter inside of `"pagination"` so you know there is still more to get.

I want to add the `"data"` section of each object into one big object so I can then loop through these and map them on a google map in 1 go.

To give you an example:

```
obj1 = {
  "pagination": {
    ...
  },
  "meta": {
    ...
  },
  "data": [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}

obj2 = {
  "pagination": {
    ...
  },
  "meta": {
    ...
  },
  "data": [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The Result:

```
obj3 = {
  "data": [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The `"pagination"` and `"meta"` sections do not need to be merged together, I just need a big long list of all the data.

I hope you can help, if you need any more info / data please ask.

**EDIT**

I have realised I do not need `obj3` and thanks to Brian's answer I have come to a solution:

```
obj1 = {
  data: []
};

obj1.data = obj1.data.concat(obj2.data);
```

Thanks Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need something like this if I understand question right:

```
obj3 = obj1;
obj1.data = obj2.data.concat(obj2.data)
```

Basically concatenate the arrays.  Only issue would be if there's duplicates to merge, but it sounds like it's a simple adding of lists?

Comment: There will be no duplicates as I will always request the next set of data from Instagram, I will give this a go, thanks.

Comment: It's good, except for the part `obj3=obj1`.
How about `obj1.data=obj1.data.concat(obj2.data.concat(obj3))`

Comment: Yeah in practice, I would do it inline like that, but I was trying to keep to his variable names for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thanks mate, you have helped me get to the solution I need, check out the edit in my question.

Comment: @lukehillonline Please mark this as the accepted answer, that's better than editing your question to contain the answer.

Comment: @JuanMendes I was waiting for the timer to end and it was 3am for me so I went to bed